# DCC Fatal Error F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001)

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, delphi, linker

1. Delphi 10 Seattle Version update1 (installed on Win7) cannot have my project passed building after I upgraded my macOS to Sierra and XCode from 7 to 8.1.(installed on miniMac)

The error message failed my delphi project was:

> *[DCC Error] E2597 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FC:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS10.1.sdk\System\Library\PrivateFrameworks'
>   ld: file too small (length=0) for architecture arm64 [DCC Fatal Error]
>   F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001)*
>
> Failed

2. SDK is iPhoneOS 10.1

3. I've tried many times of "clean" and "build", it simply didn't work at all.

4. What's more, the iOS simulator was broken as well with the error message:

> Class linkage error..

5. The PAServer version is 17.1

6. After the macOS and XCode upgrade, SDK re-downloaded to the Win7 PC side.

Any idea about this issue? Is that because of the macOS and XCode upgrade? Thanks!

Comment: The error message says a directory doesn't exist. Obvious first question: *Does* that directory exist?

Comment: @Rob, this directory is not there since iOS9.3 -- a known issue. is this the root cause?

Comment: I have same problem. are you using Parallels on your MacOS? I think this problem belongs to Parallels shared folders. And your platform local cache files not copied completely.

Comment: @mehdi, thanks for your reply. the fact is that I am not using Parallels on my MacOS (Sierra). I have one PC installed with Win7(64bit) and one MiniMac just upgraded from EI Captian to Sierra. Both locate in a LAN and connecting to internet with NAT.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still wonders. I simply restarted xCode and shift+cmd+k my project and it worked like that :)

And I do have Parallel on my machine